# $H^n_c(X;\Bbb Z)=\Bbb Z_2$ for a nonorientable connected $n$-manifold $X$, proof given in Dold's Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homology-cohomology, orientation

The following is contained in Example 6.25 in p.289 of Dold's *Lectures on Algebraic Topology*.

**Proposition.** If $X$ is a nonorientable connected $n$-manifold then $H^n_c(X;\Bbb Z)=\Bbb Z_2$.

Proof) Consider the direct system $\{K\}$ of connected compact subsets of $X$ such that $X$ is not orientable along $K$. Then $H^n_c(X;\Bbb Z)=\text{colim} H^n(X,X-K;\Bbb Z)$. By universal coefficient theorem $H^n(X,X-K;\Bbb Z)=\text{Hom}(H_n(X,X-K;\Bbb Z),\Bbb Z)\oplus \text{Ext}(H_{n-1}(X,X-K;\Bbb Z), \Bbb Z)$. $H_n(X,X-K;\Bbb Z)=0$ by Corollary 3.4 and the torsion subgroup of $H_{n-1}(X,X-K;\Bbb Z)$ is $\Bbb Z_2$ by Corollary 3.5. Thus $H^n(X,X-K;\Bbb Z)=\Bbb Z_2$ and the result follows.

Question: How do we know that $H^n(X,X-K;\Bbb Z)=\Bbb Z_2$? Since we don't know that $H_{n-1}(X,X-K;\Bbb Z)$ is finitely generated, don't we know that $\text{Ext}(H_{n-1}(X,X-K;\Bbb Z), \Bbb Z)=\Bbb Z_2$?

Comment: It is claimed that $H_{n-1}(X, X - K; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$; the proof even gives a reference (corollary 3.5).  Have you taken a look at that corollary?

Comment: @JHF Corollary 3.5 only says that the "torsion subgroup" of $H_{n-1}(X,X-K;\Bbb Z)$ is $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: WLOG, assume $K$ is a compact submanifold of $X$.  By excision, $H_{n-1}(X, X-K) \cong H_{n-1}(K, \partial K)$, which is finitely generated.

Comment: @JHF How can we assume that? Is it true that every compact subset of $X$ is contained in a compact submanifold? Also for a compact submanifold $K$ how excision imply that $H_{n-1}(X,X-K)\cong H_{n-1}(K,\partial K)$? I think $\partial K$ should have a sort of tubular neighborhood to use excision, but I'm curious about this because I'm not in the smooth category.

Comment: Ok, not working in the smooth category requires some technical workarounds in certain dimensions.  For compact exhaustion by submanifolds, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/129321).  For existence of collar neighborhoods, see Hatcher, proposition 3.42.